# How to receive a success message from Teradata to R?

Tags: r, teradata-sql-assistant

first time poster here. I’m using R to ‘automate’ some Teradata (TD) SQL scripts. The ones that return data are working great. But I have an UPDATE SQL statement that only returns a message in TD like ‘xxx rows updated’. I’m using the RODBC package in R for my connection. When I use ‘sqlQuery’ and send the ‘update’ SQL statement to TD from R, I get nothing back, whether successful or not. I know only data returning is normal here, but what I want is to get that message back from TD to R. Then I can continue to ‘automate’ things based on the message. Is there a way, either in putting something in the SQL code at the end, or afterwards with R, to get this ‘successful’ message back?
Package RODBC has “odbcGetErrMsg”, but it doesn’t work on the success message. The only workaround I can think of is to do a count(*) before the update, then send the update statement, then count(*) after to get a number of rows changed. This may work, but I’d like to get the message instead. I’ve searched SO & Googled this with no luck. Any ideas of how to get a successful TD message from an update statement sent from R returned back in R please?

Comment: That message is actually constructed by the client application and not the driver or the database. The driver returns a "number of rows" whenever a statement is executed, and RODBC does use that information internally in the case of a SELECT. But it seems that it does not pass the value back to the R application. The "Teradata SQL Driver for R" (rather than RODBC) might be an option.

Comment: You might also want to check out the [**`DBI`**](https://dbi.r-dbi.org) package, which is actively maintained within the [**`tidyverse`**](https://www.tidyverse.org); in tandem with the [**`odbc`**](https://db.rstudio.com/r-packages/odbc) package.  **`DBI`** serves as a standardized API for the "front-end", while **`odbc`** implements the "back-end".